# perl in-place sort lines in a text file

Tags: python, perl

I wish to modify a text file by sorting each line based on a given key and save the old file as a backup.  The key is a numeric character contained in each line.

Is there a simple script to get this done, preferably in-place?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that doing this in-place would be extremely inefficient. Sorting requires reordering, and doing that in-place means moving the entire contents of the file repeatedly. Why are you asking for it to be done in-place rather than in memory? You should state your needs rather than binding our hands with a specific "solution" if you want a good answer.

Comment: Have you tried the 'sort' program?  'sort' is normally available on all nix platforms.

Comment: The `sort` utility works in memory using temporary files if necessary, not in-place. It's definitely a great and efficient tool, though.

Comment: You'll get more helpful answers if you provide a sample of your input.

Answer (score 1):

There are in-place sorting algorithms with O(n log n) complexity such as [Heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort%20Heapsort), but I don't see why you would want to use that rather than something simple such as the Unix `sort` command. Unless you have stringent performance requirements or huge datasets... but then, perl and python probably aren't the best tools for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Say your sort key is the run of digits at the beginning of each line, as in the following example.

```
5 Fine
2 Good
1 Every
4 Does
3 Boy
```

To sort one or more files named on the command line, you can use the code below.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 file ..\n" unless @ARGV;

$^I = ".bak";
undef $/;

while (<>) {
  print map $_->[0],
        sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
        map { [ $_, /^(\d+)/ ? $1 : -1 ] }
        /^(.*\n?)/mg;
}
```

[`@ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40ARGV) contains the arguments from the command line. Running the program with no arguments produces a usage guide on the standard error.

[`$^I`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5eI) holds the extension added to filenames when creating backups for in-place editing, which you can also enable with Perl's `-i` switch, covered in the [perlrun documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

> **-i[extension]**
>   specifies that files processed by the `<>` construct are to be edited in-place. It does this by renaming the input file, opening the output file by the original name, and selecting that output file as the default for `print` statements.

[`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%2f) is the input record separator. Setting it to the undefined value means you want subsequent calls to the [readline operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) to read through end-of-file. Performance will suffer with very large inputs.

On each iteration of the `while` loop, the special variable `$_` will hold the contents of the current file as a whole. To sort the lines, we first break them apart.

Don't be intimidated by the `print` inside the loop. It's the [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), a common technique in Perl even though it debuted to [less-than-rave reviews](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.perl.misc/msg/9f3595d4acd4f58d?hl=en). To understand what's happening, read it from the end to the beginning.

1. Capture a list of all lines in the current file. The `/m` regex switch makes `^` match at the beginning of a line, not only at the beginning of the target string.
2. For each line, attempt to capture one or more digits at the beginning of that line or default to -1.
3. Sort the lines in ascending order of the sort key.
4. Finally, print the lines in sorted order. With in-place editing enabled, `print` outputs to the current file being sorted.

In a more procedural style, you'd write the loop as

```
while (<>) {
  my @lines = /^(.*\n?)/mg;
  my @augmented = map { [ $_, /^(\d+)/ ? $1 : -1 ] } @lines;
  my @sorted = sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @augmented;
  print map $_->[0], @sorted;
}
```

Once you understand what's happening with the Schwartzian Transform, all the temporaries seem like undue clutter.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple script to do this because what you're suggesting is actually fairly complex and inefficient. Unless your lines are all the exact same length in the file, it's almost impossible (or, incredibly silly).

If you absolutely can't do it in memory and want to write the code yourself, your best approach is probably a [disk based merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). The example for how you would do it with tape drives should give you some guidance.